# Raphael JS + Click Handler

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, click, raphael

I am trying to get a "3d" cube to listen to my clicks when I click on a specific face of the cube, but I keep getting an error.

The code: http://jsfiddle.net/qa3P7/1/

In the winload function, I have added the following code:

```
cube.object[0].click(function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

But it returns:`Object #<Object> has no method 'click'`

When I do: `cube.object[0]`, I do get the correct "face" of the cube:

```
cube.object[0]
Object
bl: Array[3]
br: Array[3]
c: "url("img/cube/bianco.jpg")"
clip: 123.18126918267271
id: "face_2"
normal: Array[2]
object: z
shadow: null
tl: Array[3]
tr: Array[3]
__proto__: Object
```

I am pretty new to all this and after hours of trying and researching, I am stuck.

Comment: It's an object called `cube` created by this library. but `cube.object[0].object` represents a Raphael element, but I wasn't able to get it work. `console.log(cube.object[0].object)` always returns `null`, and I don't know why. When I log only `cube` and click through the object in the developer console, I see all methods and properties. Very strange...

Comment: @DanLee Thats exactly what happens when I try it too. When selecting the `cube.object[0].object` by clicking through the chrome console, I can see all methods and stuff, but when writing `console.log(cube.object[0].object)` it always returns `null`. I have no idea why :(

Comment: Have you considered using Three.js?

Answer (score 0):

This is problematic, since every visible face of the cube is redrawn anew on each frame (see `drawFrame`), and `.click()` is a method of a Raphael path, in this case referred to as `face.object`. You could try reassigning the click handler every time the face is redrawn, but I think a better approach would be to catch the click on the level of canvas and identify the face under the cursor manually.

Comment: I did more or less the same thing using `getImageData` to identify the pixel color that is currently under the cursor and than linked the color to the specific side, however when using images, instead of plain colors for each side, things are getting complitcated.

Comment: I don't think it's too hard mathematically, given that you know the exact transformation of the cube at any point in time and even the coordinates of its visible faces (as they are calculated in `drawQuad`).